# Django-AWS gzip compression not enabled?

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, gzip

I followed this tutorial: https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/ to deploy my Django site to AWS. Everything works fine, but when I use Google's PageSpeed, it tells me that gzip is not enabled. Here are two files:

03_apache.config

```
container_commands:
  01_setup_apache:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
```

enable_mod_deflate.conf

```
# mod_deflate configuration
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Restrict compression to these MIME types
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml+rss
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  # Level of compression (Highest 9 - Lowest 1)
  DeflateCompressionLevel 9
  # Netscape 4.x has some problems.
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
  BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Those are located in .ebextensions and should be able to setup gzip. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NGINX instead of Apache. Nginx came onto the scene after Apache, with more awareness of the concurrency problems that would face sites at scale. Leveraging this knowledge, Nginx was designed from the ground up to use an asynchronous, non-blocking, event-driven connection handling algorithm.

NGINX Configuration are comfortable to use than Apache.

For gzip compression follow this [link.](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-configure-gzip-compression-with-nginx/)